# Transform keys in form request after validation

Tags: laravel

I want to transform the keys of my data in a form request (after validation), so I have a method:

```
 public function data()
{
    return [
        'my_title' => $this->input('title'),
        'my_body' => $this->input('body'),
    ];
}
```

Which is accessed in a controller via:

```
$request->data()
```

I know I can access each part by:

```
$request->data()['my_title']
```

But how can I set this up so it can be accessed like:

```
$request->data('my_title')
```

or even

```
$request->data->my_title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want this pattern

```
$request->data()->my_title
```

then you must data method return an object not an array:

```
 public function data()
{
    $array= [
        'my_title' => $this->input('title'),
        'my_body' => $this->input('body'),
    ];
    $objectFromArray=(object)$array;
  return $objectFromArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$var = $request->all();
$var['item_in_request'];
//or
$request->item_in_request; //property accessed via magic method
```

but my recommendation is to always use:

```
$request->input('item_in_request'); 
$request->get('item_in_request');
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.